# Why does keyboard tabbing the focus on the hidden buttons push up the div on top in the HTML and the box title?

Tags: html, css

Hover over the box to see the two buttons appear. I want it so that when tabbing, for accessibility, the buttons appear but without pushing up the div and title inside the div on top of it.

Tabbing to a link within the description div pushes up the div with the class of img-block.

Why is it doing this and how can I correct it?

```css
#square .square-wrapper-inner {
  height: 50%; /* Changed from 100%*/
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  top: 250px; /* Changed from 600 */
  padding: 15px 20px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.1s;
  -moz-transition: 0.1s;
  -ms-transition: 0.1s;
  -o-transition: 0.1s;
  transition: 0.1s;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8) !important;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#square {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
#square h2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -40%);
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center !important;
  font-family: "Merriweather", serif !important;
  font-size: 20px !important;
  letter-spacing: 0.8px;
  line-height: 24px !important;
  color: #fff !important;
  text-shadow: 0 0 7px rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-weight: 700 !important;
}

#square .description a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #000 !important;
  color: #fff !important;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center !important;
  font-family: "Karla", sans-serif !important;
  font-size: 14px !important;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#square .description a:hover,
#square .description a:focus {
  color: #fff;
}

#square .description a:first-child {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#square img {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: top;
}

#square .square-wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}

#square .square-wrapper:hover .square-wrapper-inner,
#square .square-wrapper:focus .square-wrapper-inner {
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="square">
  <div class="square-wrapper">
    <div class="img-block" style="background-color: #000; width: 250px; height: 250px;" >
      <h2>Box Title</h2>
    </div>
    
    <div class="square-wrapper-inner">
      <div class="description">
        <a href="#">Link #1</a>
        <a href="#">Link #2</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you use the code snippet button? That makes it so you can run your code on the page and allows other people to run it as well.

Comment: @xdhmoore Can you see the edit button? That makes it so you can edit anyone's question

Comment: @j08691 Thanks, that didn't even occur to me. I'll keep that in mind in the future!

Comment: @xdhmoore I'm sorry. I am new to this again. I've created the 'Run code snippet' button. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the `overflow: hidden` property on the `.square-wrapper` element. According to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow#values), `overflow: hidden` still allows programmatic scrolling within the element, while `overflow: clip` does not.

So when you tab, the interior of `.square-wrapper` is scrolling down to the focused element.

Unfortunately, it turns out that `overflow:clip` is only supported on the [most recent version of Chrome, 90](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_overflow_clip), so if you need this for a userbase than may not have the most recent version of Chrome, you won't be able to use it.

The other issue is that you can't use `:focus` on a `div`. The `<a>` tags are the only elements receiving focus here. You *can* use [:focus-within](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within), and that will cause the trigger you want, I think.

So:

`overflow:hidden` -> `overflow:clip`
`.square-wrapper:focus` -> `.square-wrapper:focus-within`

See below:

```css
#square .square-wrapper-inner {
  height: 50%; /* Changed from 100%*/
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  top: 250px; /* Changed from 600 */
  padding: 15px 20px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.1s;
  -moz-transition: 0.1s;
  -ms-transition: 0.1s;
  -o-transition: 0.1s;
  transition: 0.1s;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8) !important;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#square {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
#square h2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -40%);
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center !important;
  font-family: "Merriweather", serif !important;
  font-size: 20px !important;
  letter-spacing: 0.8px;
  line-height: 24px !important;
  color: #fff !important;
  text-shadow: 0 0 7px rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-weight: 700 !important;
}

#square .description a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #000 !important;
  color: #fff !important;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center !important;
  font-family: "Karla", sans-serif !important;
  font-size: 14px !important;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#square .description a:hover,
#square .description a:focus {
  color: #fff;
}

#square .description a:first-child {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#square img {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: top;
}

#square .square-wrapper {
  overflow: clip; /* CHANGED THIS */
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}

#square .square-wrapper:hover .square-wrapper-inner,
#square .square-wrapper:focus-within .square-wrapper-inner { /* CHANGED THIS */
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="square">
  <div class="square-wrapper">
    <div class="img-block" style="background-color: #000; width: 250px; height: 250px;" >
      <h2>Box Title</h2>
    </div>
    
    <div class="square-wrapper-inner">
      <div class="description">
        <a href="#">Link #1</a>
        <a href="#">Link #2</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you@xdhmoore for your reply. I'm unsure if I should then ask a brand new question in a new post? How can I keep the usability that I had? For example, the two buttons were hidden and appear when hovering over the black box. Tabbing to the buttons made them appear over the black box. I want to keep that usability. Does this require javascript and for me to ask a question related to that? Or can this be accomplished with CSS alone? With the overflow: clip; the buttons are visible at all times which I don't want.

Comment: For me, in the snippet above, they only appear when hovering over. Does that not happen for you? Also, did you want them to appear when tabbing to them? Maybe I misunderstood the question...

Comment: Oh, you want them to do the same thing when tabbing as when hovering?

Comment: Yes, @xdmoore. I want the buttons to become visible when tabbing so that they appear as a pop-up over the black box. I want persons using a keyboard to access the buttons for accessibility.

I viewed your code in Firefox and that fixed the issue of me not seeing the buttons until I hovered over the black box. Initially, I was using Chrome and was seeing the buttons at all times.

Comment: I am indeed a Fx user. I've added 1 more tweak so the tabbing triggers the popup. How does it look now?

Comment: Looks like they [just](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_overflow_clip) added `overflow: clip` to Chrome. I literally saw it not working, then updated Chrome and it worked.

Comment: For some reason when I test out the tabbing in FF it doesn't make the buttons appear. It's as though it is ignoring them. Is it working for you?

Comment: I have to click "Run code snippet", then "Full page", then I have to click the background. Then tabbing works for me and pulls up the popup.

Comment: Thank you, @xdhmoore! I'm happy with the results.

Comment: Glad to hear it!